# Neo4j - Saved Scripts in Browser Interface Not Saving

Tags: neo4j, nosql, graph-databases

I'm just curious - have any fellow Neo4j-ers ever encountered this behavior?

Right now, I've got 30 queries in the 'Saved Scripts' part of the Neo4j browser interface. When I try to save another, it will remain there until the the page is reloaded/refreshed - it then disappears.

I thought that 30 might be some soft limit determined in a Neo4j configuration file (/etc/neo4j/neo4.conf) but I can't find any statements in the file relating to this. If it's at all pertinent, I'm running x64 CentOS 7 as a VM - this is where my Neo4j has been configured. I've checked the debug logs and I don't see any warnings or errors relevant to this issue.

Is this behavior normal? If so, is there a way to change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. Just needed to reboot the VM apparently.

Still not sure what the root cause of this is - but rebooting was, in this case, the remedy.